# Rails Search Ransack NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack, nomethoderror, search-form

This app has 2 models, a Farm has_many Crops. We are trying to use ransack to do the searching on Farm#show. The show action in the controller looks like this:

```
  def show
    @farm = Farm.find(params[:id])
    @q = @farm.crops.ransack(params[:q])
    @crops = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end
```

The Farm#show View contains this form:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :croptype_cont, "Crop Name Contains:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :croptype_cont %>
  </div>
<%= f.submit "search" %>
<% end %>
```

Everything looks right to me, but we keep getting this error - it highlights the first line of the search form:

> NoMethodError in Farms#show 
>   undefined method `crops_path'

What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Because by default ranksack search goes to index action, you can see in its documentation which is `crops_path`, Here You'll have to write a separate action for searching. or you can do like this

1- modify your show action and define only `@q` as search variable

```
  def show
    @farm = Farm.find(params[:id])
    @q = @farm.crops.ransack(params[:q])
  end
```

2- create a separate action for search ex-

```
def search_crops
  @farm = Farm.find(params[:id])
  @q = @farm.crops.ransack(params[:q])
  @crops = @q.result(distinct: true) 
end
```

3- define url for search_crops

```
get 'search/farm/crops', to: 'farms#search_crops', as: :crops_search
```

4- in `farms/show.html.erb` send a hidden field `id` to get farm before searching crops associated with farm

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: crops_search_path, :html => { :method => :get } do |f| 
  <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: params[:id] %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :croptype_cont, "Crop Name Contains:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :croptype_cont %>
  </div>
<%= f.submit "search" %>
<% end %>
```

5- so after getting `@crops` from `search_crops` action You can either make common partial for `show.html.erb` as well as `search_crops.html.erb`
and display search results.You can modify your code accordingly